# How to get started with Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I want to create web application using Visual Studio 2012.
The application should login into a website and report numerical findings on the UI.

The language used will be Visual C#.

I have loaded the application and selected on the menu: File> New > Projects.

A window appears with multiple options.
I am starting to learn about programming language such as C# and Visual Basic.

[image: "New project" window appearing]

Would I be able to have a bit of help on this.

Thank you :)

Comment: Search your title text in Google. You will find several articles or tutorials to help you not just a bit but a lot ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner's guides to Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605374/beginners-guides-to-visual-studio)

Comment: there are loads of tutorials on how to start writting an application, put a bit of effort into searching before asking here for help !

Comment: @MihaiTibrea I'm aware I am currently searching but Microsoft explanation wasn't the best at all for a beginner and from a non programming perspective it's not as clear the difference between asp.net mvc4 and asp.net mv4. I can understand it seems like common sense for most people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this book "Microsoft ASP.NET 4 Step By Step" by George Shepherd.I found it very helpful.It will address all the issues you raised here.Thank you.